# A single word for an "instance" of publicity

Tags: single-word-requests, grammatical-number, nouns

Is there a non-collective noun for an "instance" of publicity?

In other words, a restaurant receives publicity every time a local newspaper publishes a review or an article about it. Each of those articles or reviews are examples of a *[blank]* for the restaurant?

Comment: Cowboy - I figured it would be a lot cleaner if I deleted my original answer and posted a new one.  I'm fairly sure I've seen "a media exposure" used as a singular noun, but I can't find any evidence to back me up - so I might have been leading you astray.  In any case, "opportunity" is much more common.

Comment: Just to clarify - I assumed you were looking for a word for instances of "free" publicity, not paid.  Correct?

Comment: @MT_Head Thank you for the opportunity to clarify. Free publicity was my intention, though if a word has both a *free* and *paid* connotation, it would still work.

Comment: Colloquially it's called a "blurb".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Opportunity**.  It's been very widely used for years in the phrase "photo opportunity", often abbreviated as "photo op" or "photo opp", but [Ngrams shows a dramatic increase](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=media%20opportunity&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) in uses of the phrase **media opportunity**, which I think is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

In Australia, the word '*promo*' is quite common for indicating a piece of advertising material; e.g., a promotional article, review, TV segment, or whatever the case happens to be.

Another widely used colloquial term is '*plug*'...

Here's the definition from *thefreedictionary*:

> *Informal*.  A favorable public mention of a commercial product, business, or performance, especially when broadcast.

And an example:

```
"If you help me out here, I'll slip in a free plug for you next time I'm on air."
```

Comment: +1 for *plug*, as long as it's clear that you don't mean hair plugs. :-)

Comment: +1, but _plug_ is only for positive mentions, as you noted, and the questioner didn't ask for a word meaning only positive mentions.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly what you asked for, but why use the singular? You could rewrite it as "Each of those articles or reviews are examples of publicity for the company."

Answer (score 1):

a **mention**

You got a mention in the paper the other day.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a single word, but I think of two:

> [**Momentary Fame**](http://playfulutopia.com/2011/04/25/the-hall-of-momentary-fame-1981/)

Answer (score 0):

"Event" -- it applies especially to one that was planned.

Answer (score 0):

How about ***showcase***?

> A setting, occasion, or medium for exhibiting something or someone especially in an attractive or favorable aspect.

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/showcase)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the single word asked here is to replace "instance" and not "instance of publicity". So, consider

### [**shot**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/shot)

> n. a try at something.
>
> *Go ahead. Give it another shot.*

In your case, you could say:

*"Each of those articles or reviews are **shots** at publicity."*